# Testing promise functions in jest with mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, mocking, jestjs

I have below function code:

**fetchDeviceList** is bind from redux store with the help of mapStateToProps

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchDeviceList().then(() => {
      this.saveFirstClassifiedDeviceDetails();
    });
  }
```

My test code looks like below:

```
 it('should pass', () => {
    const methodNameFake = jest.spyOn(
      DeviceListContainer.prototype,
      'fetchDeviceList'
    );

    const props = {
       data: []
    };

    const connectedComponent = mount(
      <DeviceListContainer {...props} />
    );

    expect(methodNameFake).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

But getting error as:  `TypeError: this.props.fetchDeviceList is not a function`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined
```

`fetchDeviceList` is a function bound from redux directly via `mapStateToProps`

I need to understand what's the best way to test this implementation? I am new to React and this is the first time trying to write Jest test cases for promises, kindly bear with the mistakes.

Also tried;

```
component = shallow(
      <DeviceListContainer
        {...props}
        fetchDeviceList={jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => {
          return Promise.resolve('yo');
        })}
      />
    );
```

Then I get error as: `TypeError: this.props.fetchDeviceList(...).then is not a function`

Do we need to pass the props while testing, is it correct way to handle because the props data will be generated as soon as component mounts from Redux store. What's the best approach?

Anyone have an insight into what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a section in the Redux docs about testing Redux containers.

https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components

It's alluded to in the above link, but I'd recommend simply testing the inner presentational component, and not trying to test the higher order component that's returned by Redux's `connect()` function.

You're interested in unit testing code that you've written, i.e. the inner presentational component, rather than code the Redux team has written which is the result of calling `connect()`.

So something like you already had should work, as long as you just test `DeviceList` directly, not the container:

```
component = shallow(
  <DeviceList
    data={[]}
    fetchDeviceList={jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => {
      return Promise.resolve('yo');
    })}
  />
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jed Richards, its working for me which i tried, but the props are generated from `mapStateToProps` and is it correct way to pass it directly to component from UT or do we need to mock the props from spy call. How to do that is my question. Also after this gets resolved, there is a save function back to redux `this.props.saveDeviceDetails(firstClassifedDevice);` when i try to handle similar to fetchDeviceList, error in jasmine timeout.

Comment: my intention is to test both higher order compnent and presentational components, though its painful for my journey. Need to learn and be sure the tests are end to end